# Partial reverse http proxy using nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy

I've got several HTTP services running on the same machine, on different ports.  I'd like to use nginx as a reverse proxy, but I can't seem to get my setup quite right.

I'd like the following:

- `/fossil/` ==> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/fossil/index.php`
- `/fossil/(whatever)` ==> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/(whatever)`
- `/webmin/` ==> `http://127.0.0.1:10000/`
- a few more specific locations to be served by nginx itself
- and everything else to be handled by Apache ==> `http://127.0.0.1:8001`

It's the first two that seem to cause trouble; I want everything under `/fossil/` to be handled by fossil, on port 8080; except the root itself, that one has to be handled by a special PHP page (under Apache).

What would be the way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below config.

Be sure to see the comments in the `location = /fossil/` section. Also keep in mind that requests to /fossil/(whatever) become /(whatever), so any urls returned in your content should be /fossil/(whatever) and not /(whatever). If necessary you could use sub_filter on the nginx side to substitute /fossil/(whatever) for /(whatever) when the content is return to the client.

```
location = /fossil/ {
  # matches /fossil/ query only
  #
  # if Apache isn't configured to serve index.php as the index
  # for /fossil/ uncomment the below rewrite and remove or comment
  # the proxy_pass
  #
  # rewrite /fossil/ /fossil/index.php;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location = /fossil/index.php {
  # matches /fossil/index.php query only
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /fossil/ {
  # matches any query beginning with /fossil/
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}

location /webmin/ {
  # matches any query beginning with /webmin/
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
}

location / {
  # matches any query, since all queries begin with /, but regular
  # expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be
  # matched first.
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}

# locations to be handled by nginx go below
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one also works.  I’ve accepted this answer because of the tip about `sub_filter`; fossil does assume that it’s sitting in the root of the server, so I need to rewrite the URLs in the page...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly straightforward with two types of static location.  location = is an exact match, and location /location is a prefix match.  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;

  # Set defaults for the proxy_pass directives in each location
  # Add the client IP
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  # Pass through the request hostname
  proxy_set_header Host $host;

  # Everything that doesn't match a more specific location
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
  }

  location = /fossil/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/fossil/index.php;
  }

  location /fossil/ {
    # Do you really want to strip off /fossil here but not above?
    # The trailing / replaces /fossil/ with /
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }

  location /webmin/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10000/;
  }

  .. add your other locations ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this seems to do the trick! I hadn’t found the `=` prefix.  And yes, I do want to strip off fossil; I just made a mistake in my question: `/fossil/` should redirect to Apache (on :8001), `/fossil/*` should redirect to the Fossil server (on :8080).  It turns out, though, that Fossil wants to sit on the root path, so it doesn’t quite work yet.  I guess I’ll have to use a subdomain for it...